# cannot parse " +0000 UTC" as "T". Go utc time parsing error

Tags: date, go

I was trying to parse a time time between utc string back to Go time. But I'm getting an error `cannot parse "  +0000 UTC" as "T"`.

```
stringTime := time.Now().UTC().String()
t, e := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, stringTime)
fmt.Println(e)
fmt.Println(t)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HFiH9Ifk2kj)

Answer (score 3):

stringTime is not in RFC3339 format: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String

If you want to parse it, use the format in the link.